# MySQL 5.7: deprecated partitioning method warning error

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have here a couple of MySQL DB tables optimised with partitioning as in:

```
ALTER TABLE radpostauth PARTITION BY HASH(id) PARTITIONS 32;
```

With the upgrade do MySQL 5.7, the following warning started appearing in the error logs:

```
The partition engine, used by table 'y.radpostauth', is deprecated and 
will be removed in a future release. Please use native partitioning instead.
```

I have an idea I can do an `ALTER TABLE REBUILD` however, no clue about what to do to make it compliant to 5.7 and beyond.

What do you advise?

Comment: On a separate issue...  In my opinion, `PARTITION BY HASH` is useless.  What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @RickJames I only did the PARTITION to lower the load of the server due to two or 3 problematic/bigger tables. What is your recommendation?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; and a query that you think will benefit from the partitioning.  I should be able to explain further from those.

Comment: @RickJames On the move, will open a new question later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As of MySQL 5.7.17, the generic partitioning handler in the MySQL server is deprecated, and is removed in MySQL 8.0, when the storage engine used for a given table is expected to provide its own (“native”) partitioning handler. Currently, only the InnoDB and NDB storage engines do.

Use of tables with nonnative partitioning results in such warning written in error log.The MySQL server checks tables that using nonnative partitioning at startup.

To disable this check, use the `--disable-partition-engine-check` option.

Tables with nonnative partitioning should be changed to use an engine that provides native partitioning as shown below.

`ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = INNODB;`

**Reference:**

[Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html)

Comment: Related: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85830